# Error producing PDF from TeX source with with Knit and Rmarkdow - pandoc document conversion failing with error 43

Tags: r, pdf-generation, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I working on writing a quantitative finance book using R-Markdown in Rstudio with Knitr interested in produce a dynamic pdf document, but maybe I´m trying something out of my abilities given all the time and problems I´ve faced in all new conversion I try after inserting a new content like a graph, table and/or figure...probably RMarkdown with all other complexities behind the scene like Knitr, Pandoc, MIKTEX is not for a "first-time" users like me, although I already have familiarity with R and Rstudio. But my also first perception is that things are not so tied between all these elements and lots of small adjustments are required which restricts the use for people outside the program language domains.

The content I´m going to publish is really wide to place here, and I don´t expect any kind of "silver bullet" to solve my current and new futures problems to come with the next "Knitr´ing" to do, but maybe you as experts you are may have a kind of "recipe" to workaround the annoying **"pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source Erro: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43"** message I´ve received frequently.

Today my RMarkdown has 2,200 rows with dozens of chunks basically involving data reshaping, tables and graphs generations. Below I´m pasting the way I´m defining my YAML preamble definitions.

```
---
title: "My book"
author: "Me"
date: "Wednesday, July 31th, 2015"
documentclass: book
fontsize: 10pt
classoption: 
        b5paper
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   - \usepackage{longtable}
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
geometry:
- tmargin=2cm
- bmargin=2cm
- lmargin=2cm
- rmargin=2cm
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: kate
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
---
```

**The R packages being used so that you have an idea about the things I can be doing.**

````
``` {r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
require("pander")
require("knitr")
require("kfigr")
require("rmarkdown")
require("markdown")
require("yaml")
require("xtable")
require("RColorBrewer")
require("graphics")
require("lubridate")
require("data.table")
require("xts")
require("reshape2")
require("ggplot2")
require("scales")
require("plot3D")
require("coefplot")
require("dplyr")

```
````

**My environment:**

```
Rstudio: Version 0.99.482
Pandoc 1.13.2
Knitr version 1.11

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.0     yaml_2.1.13    
[4] rmarkdown_0.7   digest_0.6.8
```

**The last "stranding" involves the following chunk:**

````
```{r X11,anchor="Graph", results='asis',eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,cache=TRUE,fig.cap="Graph Bar"}

require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

file21<-file.path("C:/Users",username,"OneDrive/Git",folder,"file21.csv")
file<-read.csv(file21,sep=";")

file[,7]<-as.numeric(as.character(file[,7]))
filep[is.na(file)] <- 0.000
df<-melt(file, id.vars=c("Year"))
df$value<-as.numeric(as.character(df$value))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, fill = variable,y = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity",color="gray")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=12),legend.position="top",legend.title = element_blank()) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGY") + 
geom_text(aes(label=percent(value)), vjust=1,colour="black", position= position_stack(0.9), size=2.5)   
```
````

**Just wondering if by looking at these information you could help me to find way to succeed in the pdf document creation escaping of the error number "43"**

Many thanks in advance.

Fabio

Comment: Maybe one of these can help: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856362/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-pdflatex-the-memory-dump-file), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974670/error-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-windows-7-r-studio), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890800/knitr-preamble-error-results-in-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43)

Comment: Watch the first comment in [link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/tufte_handout_format.html)

Comment: Update your rmarkdown

Comment: Your code works for me. Silly question: have you installed a LaTeX distribution?

Comment: Most of the "error 43" I encounter are caused by pdflatex not understanding unicode characters. I see that your local is brazilian portuguese. Since the code works on SabDeM's machine, it may be that the problem is with the encoding of some diacritical characters in the body rather than with anything in a R chunk. Maybe try using xelatex rather than lualatex as a latex-engine?

Comment: Thanks to all answers.

Comment: Thanks to all. I updated the rmarkdown by devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown") and also needed to install.packages("stringi",type="mac.binary") and then got same 43 error but now with more output info and then, once again, was indicated a problem with \usepackage{amsmath} and only after removing from preamble I got the pdf conversion concluded.